# Why my s3 life cycle rule not take effect or not working

Tags: amazon-s3

I configured the life cycle rule on the s3 console, transition to Intelligent-Tiering after 0 days, applied to whole bucket, However, ten days have passed and the document is still standard storage class.
I don't know where my configuration is wrong,or where can I see life cycle rule execution log.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Comment: Sounds like something to ask AWS Support.

Comment: Can you update on this? Have you found a solution?